# login(request, user) function not working in django.contrib.auth

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I am currently building a web app using Django that requires users to login, and I have this function in views.py

```
 def post(self, request, format=None):
        login = request.data
        user = authenticate(
                username=login['username'], password=login['password'])

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return Response({'message': 'Login successful', 'status': 1})
        else:
            return Response({'message': 'Login unsuccessful', 'status': 0})
```

But the login function keeps triggering an error

```
File ".../views.py", line 58, in post
    login(request, user)
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

I don't know why the user is identified as 'dict' object. Can please anyone help me?

Comment: Your local dictionary `login` is shadowing the function. Rename your dictionary to something else

Comment: oh right! didn't realize it was that simple. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

login = request.data

changing the variable name will work.